# Swift SpriteKit losing memory after multiple scene changes

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in Swift where everything is a scene made using SpriteKit (basically just menus + game scene). Currently, I never need to save any data from one scene to the next, so I just always present a whole new scene when changing menus or going into and out of the game scene. Recently, after a few scene changes the app will crash with this weird error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

This literally just happened after going from my main menu to another scene and back a bunch of times in a row. The number of times it takes to cause an error isn't constant, it just seems kinda random. Here's an example of the scene changing code I use:

```
let new_scene = LevelEditorScene(size: CGSizeMake(self.scene!.view!.frame.width, self.scene!.view!.frame.height))
new_scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
new_scene.currentLevel = tempLevel
let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(0.5))
self.scene!.view!.presentScene(new_scene, transition: transition)
```

Every other time I change scenes uses nearly identical or identical code (basically passing in values to the next scene if needed).

Also, there is a certain combo of going from scene to scene that almost always crashes it, and this time it errors at a specific line in my code every time.

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

It always happens in this loop:

```
//CUSTOM_LEVELS is an array of CustomLevel objects, which extend SKShapeNode
for tempLevel: CustomLevel in CUSTOM_LEVELS { //I specify the type because it compiles faster, it still errors without it
    tempLevel.position = CGPoint(x: SCREEN_WIDTH * 2, y: SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) //Errors here
    self.addChild(tempLevel)
}
```

Now, I can inspect tempLevel in the debugger and it produces this:

```
expression produced error: /var/folders/4r/5bbkqbjj3rvg0nvw28r8_vdr0000gn/T/lldb/30274/expr9.swift:1:46: error: use of undeclared type 'Ricochet'
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<Ricochet.CustomLevel>(bitPattern: 0x121b24fa0).memory)
                                             ^~~~~~~~
/var/folders/4r/5bbkqbjj3rvg0nvw28r8_vdr0000gn/T/lldb/30274/expr9.swift:1:45: note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<Ricochet.CustomLevel>(bitPattern: 0x121b24fa0).memory)
                                            ^
```

See how it doesn't know what the type "Ricochet" is? Well, Ricochet is the name of the app.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have been playing around with the app on my phone and the crash hasn't been happening. Is it possible that there's a bug with the simulator? Anyway, if anyone knows what it is, I would love an explanation, but for now I'm not going to worry about it more.

Comment: Where is CUSTOM_LEVELS code? If you set CUSTOM_LEVELS (I suggest to use customLevels) var customLevels = Array<CustomLevel> the array is an array of specified objects.

Comment: Do you ever check to see if the Scene actually dies?  you may have 100 scenes just sitting in memory

Comment: Right now I am using this to initialize an empty CUSTOM_LEVELS at the beginning: `var CUSTOM_LEVELS: [CustomLevel] = []`
Is this any different from the Array one? Also, I just like to use all caps for global variables. I know, global variables are the devil, but literally every part of my app uses the same array so I thought why not use them. Lastly, how do I check to see if the scene is dead? Thanks!